# Can I change the result of the summary.lm function to another language?

Tags: r, lm

Can I change the result of the summary.lm function to another language?

I tried these...

```
trace("summary.lm", edit=T)
```

and, I modified some codes.

before

```
ans$coefficients <- cbind(Estimate = est, `Std. Error` = se, 
`t value` = tval, `Pr(>|t|)` = 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, 
  lower.tail = FALSE))
```

after

```
ans$coefficients <- cbind(추정치 = est, 표준오차 = se, 
                        `t value` = tval, `p value` = 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, 
                                                              lower.tail = FALSE))
```

but I cannot change other terms to another language
"Call:, Residuals: Min, 1Q, Median, 3Q, Max ... " and so on...

Comment: Check the `?body`

Comment: Source code is here: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/  and lm.cis here; https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-3-6-branch/src/library/stats/src/

Comment: Thank you all. I'll check it later because I'm in the middle of another task.